# WebSphere Portal - mem caching cannot be turned off in IHS

Tags: apache, apache2, websphere-portal, mod-cache

We are going to launch a brand new public site using WebSphere Portal solution, the whole incentive adopting this piece of crap was the WYSIWYG editing feature that comes with WCM for non-IT departments when it comes to content authoring.  Department head loves it!

But this is giving us endless nightmares mainly because everything, OS, WAS, WPS/WCM and IHS are all squeezed into a single box!!!.

To cut the long story short, we are fire fighting the performance issue right now among other things.

We tried to enable the **disk caching** but later found out the **mem caching** is also turned on, after reading the latest [Portal Performance Tuning Guide v1.2](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/IBM_WebSphere_Portal_V_8.0_Performance_Tuning_Guide), it says both shall not be on at the same time, so we try to turn the **mem caching** off by commenting out the enitre block `<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>`but result is that the **disk caching** is also turned off altogether.

Here's the snippet of the httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so 
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
CacheRoot /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/ihsCache
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
CacheMaxFileSize 1000000
CacheMinFileSize 1
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheIgnoreQueryString Off
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
CacheStoreNoStore Off
CacheStorePrivate Off
CacheDisable /wps/myportal/
CacheDisable /wps/mycontenthandler/
CacheDisable /wps/wcm/mycontent/
CacheEnable disk /wps/portal/
CacheEnable disk /wps/contenthandler/
CacheEnable disk /wps/wcm/content/
CacheEnable disk /wps/PA_
CacheEnable disk /mum/css/
CacheEnable disk /portal_dojo/
CacheEnable disk /DojoToolkit/
CacheEnable disk /EnhancedTheme/themes/
CacheEnable disk /wps/themeModules/themes/
CacheEnable disk /wps/defaultTheme80/themes/
</IfModule>
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so    
<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c> 
    CacheEnable mem / 
    CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie 
    MCacheSize 1024000 
    MCacheMaxObjectCount 100000 
    MCacheMinObjectSize 1 
    MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer 6291456 
    MCacheRemovalAlgorithm GDSF
    MCacheMaxObjectSize 6291456
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I have disk caching on only?

Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after reading [mod_cache not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/394871/mod-cache-not-working)

Adding `CacheEnable disk /` under `<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>` works!